# Time value not storing in the MongoDB Database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I didnt get any errors.all values are stored in to database except Time vales.

in here i get the user inputs

```
<div>
    <input type="time" name="start_time" style="width:200px" placeholder="Strat Time"/><br/>
    <input type="time" name="end_time" style="width:200px" placeholder="End Time"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="service" style="width:200px" placeholder="Service"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="client_name" style="width:200px" placeholder="Name"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="client_phone" style="width:200px" placeholder="Phone"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="amount" style="width:200px" placeholder="Amount"/><br/>
    <button>Add</button>
</div>
```

this is my model

```
var appoinmentSchema = mongoose.Schema({ start_time: Date, end_time : Date, service: String,    client_phone : String, client_name: String, amount : String })
exports.schema = mongoose.model('appoinment', appoinmentSchema);
exports.name = 'appoinment';
```

this is my server side function

```
function json_homepage() {

  var self = this;
  var Appoinment = MODEL('appoinment').schema;
  var model = self.body;
  var data = self.post;

  var appoinment = new  Appoinment({ start_time: new Date(model.start_time), end_time: new Date(model.end_time), service: model.service,client_name: model.client_name , client_phone: model.client_phone , amount:model.amount }).save(function(err) {
    console.log(data.start_time);
    console.log(model.start_time);
    if (err)
        self.throw500(err);

    // Read all users
    Appoinment.find(self.callback());
  });

}
```

this data store in MongoDB like this

```
  "start_time": {
    "$date": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "end_time": {
    "$date": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
```

-- update --

```
RangeError: Invalid time value ([object Object]) RangeError: Invalid time value
  at Date.toISOString (native)
  at Object.json_homepage (D:\Projects\examples-master\mongoose\controllers\default.js:28:68)
  at Subscribe.doExecute (D:\Projects\examples-master\mongoose\node_modules\total.js\index.js:4:4221)
  at Subscribe.execute (D:\Projects\examples-master\mongoose\node_modules\total.js\index.js:4:2949)
  at Subscribe.prepare (D:\Projects\examples-master\mongoose\node_modules\total.js\index.js:4:3911)
  at Subscribe.doEnd (D:\Projects\examples-master\mongoose\node_modules\total.js\index.js:4:6952)
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\examples-master\mongoose\node_modules\total.js\index.js:4:1808)
  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:92:17)
  at _stream_readable.js:943:16
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Any help please.i didnt see any wrong here. help me

Comment: What is this `console.log(data.start_time);` returning?

Comment: How is the date passed from the browser to the server? As a string? What format?

Comment: @majidarif it return correct value i input?but it not store in the monogDB

Comment: @Sameera please show the actual output. Thanks.

Comment: @majidarif you mena in the DB or Console?

Comment: @Sameera on the console. I have reason to believe that the this `new Date(model.start_time)` is invalid.

Comment: @max i update my question please check

Comment: @majidarif no those both logs like this
i input 12.04 Am
`00:04``00:04` this is the out put

Comment: @majidarif in my input i change this `<input type="time" name="start_time"` to `<input type="date" name="start_time"` it store right value i give

Comment: @throrin19 ok.but in my case no time valu storing

Comment: @majidarif `console.log(new Date(model.start_time));`  for this answer showing console 'Invalid Data'

Comment: @Sameera I added my answer.

Comment: @Sameera this `12.04 Am` is an invalid time. Make it `12:04 AM`. Thats causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all. I believe this is invalid:

```
new Date(model.start_time)
```

Because this:

```
<input type="time" name="start_time"/>
```

Returns a string.

One way you can fix this is by doing something like:

```
var dateToday = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US');
console.log(new Date(dateToday + '' + time));
```

### Solution

```
var dateToday = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US');

var appoinment = new Appoinment({ 
  start_time   : new Date(dateToday + '' + model.start_time), 
  end_time     : new Date(dateToday + '' + model.end_time), 
  service      : model.service,
  client_name  : model.client_name , 
  client_phone : model.client_phone , 
  amount       : model.amount 
}).save(function(err) {
```

Or you can try this:

```
start_time : new Date(dateToday + '' + model.start_time).toISOString(),
end_time   : new Date(dateToday + '' + model.end_time).toISOString(),
```

You can try it with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P4bva/58/) or here below.

```js
var calc = document.getElementById("calc")

calc.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var time = document.getElementById("start_time").value
  var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US");
  var result = new Date(date + " " + time);
  alert(result);
  alert(result.toISOString());
})
```

```html
Time:
<input id="start_time" type="time" name="start_time" />
<button id="calc">Get Time</button>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your help.finaly now its save :) +1
please can tell me what is toISOString()

Comment: @Sameera it formats the time to the ISO 8601 then turns it to a string in that format.

Comment: Thank you.Then ISO 8601 time format means UTC time?

Comment: @Sameera no, it doesn't do anything to timezone, it just formats the date.

Comment: ok.Then i save some time value `3.00 AM` but it store mongodb like this
`"start_time": {
        "$date": "2014-10-15T21:30:00.000Z"
    },`
What is that?

Comment: That is happening because of this `new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US');` try to change that.

Comment: You should open a new question.

Comment: sorry for that this is new Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399967/mongodb-date-time-value-not-storing-correctly