# MongoDB date time value not storing Correctly

Tags: javascript, mongodb

In here App Store date and time value in ISO 8601 format.but it storing some different value for Time. i save some time value `3.00` AM but it store mongodb like this 
`"start_time": { "$date": "2014-10-15T21:30:00.000Z" },`
Why is that?

```
function json_homepage() {   
    var self = this;
    var User = MODEL('user').schema;
    var model = self.body;
    var data = self.post;

    var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US");
   // var result = new Date(date + " " + time);

    var appoinment = new Appoinment({
        start_time   : new Date(date + " " + data.start_time),
        end_time     : new Date(date + '' + data.end_time),
        service      : model.service
    }).save(function(err) {
        console.log(data.start_time);
        if (err)
            self.throw500(err);
        // Read all users
      User.find(self.callback());
    });
```

### ----Update---

@Wizard's Answer -
 `It's correct. MongoDB uses ISODate to save date value. The last character Z means zero timezone. After adding your timezone, it's the value you want. So, it's only a different display format. –  Wizard`

Comment: What is the value you want? Can you give an example?

Comment: i enter 3.00 AM but it save as `"start_time": { "$date": "2014-10-15T21:30:00.000Z" }`

Comment: It's correct. MongoDB uses ISODate to save date value. The last character **Z** means zero timezone. After adding your timezone, it's the value you want. So, it's only a different display format.

Comment: @wizard   Yes you are correct :D i searched about it.Thanks for explaining it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to change this:

```
var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US");
```

To this?

```
var t = new Date();
var d = t.getDate();
var m = t.getMonth() + 1;
var y = t.getFullYear();

var date = m + '/' + d + '/' + y;
```

Or maybe the date is being changed to another timezone somewhere, though I am not sure where. You'll have to look that up.

I believe `"2014-10-15T21:30:00.000Z"`, where `Z` = `ZULU` is `UTC`. What is your servers/mongo timezone?

Comment: how can i check that im using MongoLAB

Comment: no i check with `3.04 AM` it shows `"$date": "2014-10-15T21:34:00.000Z"`

Comment: @Sameera can you console.log this `new Date(date + " " + data.start_time)` before creating the new appointment?

Comment: I INSERT `5.31 AM` console log `Thu Oct 16 2014 17:31:00 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)`
in db ` "$date": "2014-10-16T12:01:00.000Z" `

Comment: ` "start_time" : ISODate("2014-10-
16T01:37:00Z") ` in my localdatabase like this